# How to represent the condition by mathematical

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matlab

I have a condtion as 
$$T(x)= 
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if }x <a  \\ 
0 & \text{if }a\le x \le b \\ 
1 & \text{if }x >b
\end{cases}
$$

I want to represent the above condition as one formula. Could you help me please. This is my formula that I try

$T(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x-a)\cdot(b-x)$
Is it posible if I use $\tanh$ function to represent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\text{sign}(x-a)+\text{sign}(x-b)\right]$

Comment: Thank sir. Is possible if I represent it by tanh function? It look like simple than sign function